# How to show different entries from data tables on as a dropdown box option?

Tags: python, django

Hi this is my DB table for job title https://www.screencast.com/t/tse1qsnJI

And this from employee table

https://www.screencast.com/t/uMtmowCg

How could I show the job titles on the drop down box and not the job_title_id as options?

https://dpaste.de/SpAe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class JobChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, job_model_instance):
        return f'{job_model_instance.job_title}'

class AssignJobForm(forms.Form):
    job_option= JobChoiceField(
        YourModelName.objects.all(), to_field_name="pk",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'pd-10 form-control'})
    )
    # you can remove widget here.
    # you can add more fields as per your requirements.
    # job_option filed will be dropdown list here.
```

**YourModelName** = Model in which job titles are defined.

**job_model_instance** = doesn't matter. leave it as it is.